# Будет ли шифроваться boolean и int значения?

Tags: java

Мне нужно выполнить простое шифрование в `SharedPreferences`.

Вот я нашел таких 2 простых метода, один для того чтоб зашифровать другой, чтоб наоборот, получить данные.

```
private static String encrypt(String input) {
    return Base64.encodeToString(input.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}

private static String decrypt(String input) {
    return new String(Base64.decode(input, Base64.DEFAULT));
}
```

И использовать их нужно вот так

```
// Write
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("some_prefs_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString(encrypt("password"), encrypt("dummypass"));
editor.apply(); // Or commit if targeting old devices

// Read
SharedPreferences preferences =  getSharedPreferences("some_prefs_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
String pass = preferences.getString(decrypt("password"), "default");
```

И вот у меня вопрос, будет ли этот метод корректно работать при сохранении и получении boolean и int значений? Так как в этом примере показано как работать со `String`...

Comment: Это не имеет к шифорванию никакого отношения, так что лучше методы encrypt и decrypt переименовать, чтоб не вводить читателей в заблуждение

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ваши методы могут работать только с типом `String`, так как в Java статическая типизация. Однако для работы с типами `boolean` и `int` вы можете использовать преобразование их в строку и обратно методами `toString()` и `valueOf()` соответствующих классов-обёрток.

[Boolean.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#toString(boolean))

[Boolean.valueOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))

[Integer.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int))

[Integer.valueOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))

Отмечу что в таком случае для типа `boolean` возможно лишь два результата вывода вашей функции (соответствующие значениям `true` и `false`).

Также отмечу что указанные вами реализации функций не выполняют шифрования строки (они даже не берут на вход ключ шифрования), они просто преобразуют строку в кодировку [Base64](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Если вам необходимо действительно шифровать текст, попробуйте посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486121/why-is-the-ciphertext-32-bytes-long-when-encrypting-16-bytes-with-aes?rq=1), [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554296/simple-java-aes-encrypt-decrypt-example).

Comment: Ок, спасибо! Ну тогда как для заключения... Мне кажется, что этой кодировки будет достаточно, просто для того, чтоб если юзер по рутом залезет в файл преф ему не захотелось что то менять, так как ничего не понятно... Как считаете?

Comment: Да, согласен с вами. Правда если заранее известно что в файле должны быть текстовые данные (к примеру, если это файл электронной почты), то можно догадаться что это Base64. А можно и не догадаться :)

Comment: Фактор лени для обычного пользователя довольно существенен, но Вы можете случайно создать "рынок" для тех, кому будет не лень разбирать "запутанные" данные для ленивых.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Можно дополнительно к Base64 обработать строку [по маске XOR](https://habrahabr.ru/post/183462/) и это уже будет не лень разбирать  только сильно заинтересованному в расшифровке "злодею", а реализовать такое шифрование очень просто.

Comment: В принципе можно применить простой шифр замены с захардкоженной таблицей замен. Т.е. фактически заюзать ту же Base64, только не дефолтную, а свою. Если ваш файл малого размера и открытый текст не сильно похож на текст естественного языка (что как раз характерно для файлов конфигурации), то, вероятно, даже частотный анализ потенциальному взломщику ничего не даст. А разбирать вручную -- лень.

Comment: UPD: нет, немного наврал. Как раз частотный анализ и может дать результаты. У шифротекста будет две особенности:
1) из-за цифр (int) будут примерно одинаково часто встречаться некие 10 символов шифротекста.
2) boolean -- будут часто повторяться блоки по 4 (true) и 5 (false) символов шифротекста.